# Google Map API key can only be used once in phonegap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a phonegap application and i want to load google maps into my app.BUT i can only load it once from a API key and the second time i try to load the map,it  won't load. Is there a solution to this problem?

I heard using MapKit is the only solution.Is that correct?

```
https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/) case,
you can remove the map using `map.remove()`, then `map.getMap()` again.
But this plugin's map is singleton, so you can not display two maps at the same time.

[image]

Comment: No i want a fix to my API issue